# Slick.js: How to write for loop with an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, slick.js

I'm trying to implement slide numbers for each of my galleries using slick.js.

My code works well, but I believe it could be written much easier than repeating every line of code for each id. Since I have a lot of galleries in my original document, this gets really messy.
I am familiar with arrays, but I don't know how the code should be written with a "for" loop in jQuery.

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $status = $('.pagingInfo');

  $('#doc12-1').on('init reInit afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    //currentSlide is undefined on init -- set it to 0 in this case (currentSlide is 0 based)
    var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
    $status.text(i + '/' + slick.slideCount);
  });

  var $status2 = $('.pagingInfo2');

  $('#doc11-1').on('init reInit afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
    $status2.text(i + '/' + slick.slideCount);
  });

  $('.gallery').slick({
    fade: true,
    dots: false,
    prevArrow: false,
    nextArrow: false,
    speed: 0,
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="medium">

  <figure id="doc12-1" class="gallery">

    <div><img data-lazy="p/doc12/repros/doc12-1.jpg"></div>
    <div><img data-lazy="p/doc12/repros/doc12-2.jpg"></div>
    <div><img data-lazy="p/doc12/repros/doc12-3.jpg"></div>

  </figure>
  <span class="pagingInfo"></span>
</div>

<div class="medium">

  <figure id="doc11-1" class="gallery">

    <div><img data-lazy="p/doc11/repros/doc11-1.jpg"></div>
    <div><img data-lazy="p/doc11/repros/doc11-2.jpg"></div>
    <div><img data-lazy="p/doc11/repros/doc11-3.jpg"></div>

  </figure>
  <span class="pagingInfo2"></span>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create an array of ids (`['doc12-1', 'doc11-1', ...]`) and loop on them; or, I would suggest putting a specific class name to all the elements you want to loop through and put the `.on()` in the body of the loop.

You can choose to use [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) or [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) as the looping construct.

EDIT: I just realized, you won't need to loop at all, when you do $('.gallery'), and run a .on() on that collection, it'll assign the function() to all of the elements for that filter.

The status element for each of the doc element can be put inside a `data-status-filter` attribute that you can fetch for each element while looping through it.

The snippet below will not work as I haven't added slick to it yet - it'll give you an idea though.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.gallery').on('init reInit afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
      var currentStatusFilter = $(this).data().statusFilter;
      console.log(currentStatusFilter);
      var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
      $(currentStatusFilter).text(i + '/' + slick.slideCount);
  });

  $('.gallery').slick({
    fade: true,
    dots: false,
    prevArrow: false,
    nextArrow: false,
    speed: 0,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="medium">

  <figure id="doc12-1" class="gallery" data-status-filter=".pagingInfo">

    <div><img data-lazy="p/doc12/repros/doc12-1.jpg"></div>
    <div><img data-lazy="p/doc12/repros/doc12-2.jpg"></div>
    <div><img data-lazy="p/doc12/repros/doc12-3.jpg"></div>

  </figure>
  <span class="pagingInfo"></span>
</div>

<div class="medium">

  <figure id="doc11-1" class="gallery" data-status-filter=".pagingInfo2">

    <div><img data-lazy="p/doc11/repros/doc11-1.jpg"></div>
    <div><img data-lazy="p/doc11/repros/doc11-2.jpg"></div>
    <div><img data-lazy="p/doc11/repros/doc11-3.jpg"></div>

  </figure>
  <span class="pagingInfo2"></span>
</div>
```